# Error in setting procedure MySQL 5.5 with insert query

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Getting error as "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')"

I dont find any wrong syntax in my coding but still unable to find the issue,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetAssignTask(IN module varchar(100),IN did int,IN actstatus int,IN  act varchar(30),IN sdate datetime,IN edate datetime,OUT outmsg varchar(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE DateDuration int;
SET DateDuration = SELECT DATEDIFF(edate, sdate) ;
insert into sch_taskassigned   (Duration,Module,Content,Deptid,taskenddate,taskstartdate,activestatus,activity,subactivity)values (DateDuration,modul,conte,did,edate,sdate,actstatus,act,subact);
set outmsg = 'Added Successfully';
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only syntax issues I can see from looking is

`SET DateDuration = (SELECT DATEDIFF(edate, sdate));` notice I've added () after the equals.

Also depending on the client you're executing this on, you may need to change the delimiter, for example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetAssignTask(IN module varchar(100),IN did int,IN actstatus int,IN  act varchar(30),IN sdate datetime,IN edate datetime,OUT outmsg varchar(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE DateDuration int;
SET DateDuration = (SELECT DATEDIFF(edate, sdate));
insert into sch_taskassigned   (Duration,Module,Content,Deptid,taskenddate,taskstartdate,activestatus,activity,subactivity)values (DateDuration,modul,conte,did,edate,sdate,actstatus,act,subact);
set outmsg = 'Added Successfully';
END

$$
```